# Can I make this javascript slideshow play automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I had a hard time finding a decent looking slideshow, but I finally found one using jQuery. http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/

I like the smooth transition, but I don't like that I have to click to display the next slide. Is there a way to set this slide show on a timer, and perhaps randomize the order of the slides? I'm just a beginner with jQuery and javascript and can't seem to figure this out on my own.

Thanks in advance. Here's my code
http://jsfiddle.net/NB3sr/

Answer (score 1):

you can use setInterval(function, time) to call the next slide function automatically.
EX

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#rightControl').trigger('click');
  }, 4000
);
```

4000 is 4 seconds

Comment: That's great! I expected it to repeat instead of just end like that, though. Would it be complicated to loop? What sort of loop would I use here?